# Workflow Check condition is not saved in CRM 2013 and CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, workflow, dynamics-crm-2013

I navigate to Processes  --> Create new Workflow -- > Add Check Condition --> I set the condition --> Save & Close and then i find the condition isn't saved. If i click on the condition it's empty and i have to set it again.  Has any body experienced the same behaviour ?

Comment: are you using Google Chrome? did you try with Internet Explorer?

Comment: I've experienced this in Chrome before, so I am wondering if Guido is on to something.

Comment: yes, I wrote about this issue in my blog http://www.crmanswers.net/2014/09/google-chrome-registry-fix-for-dynamics.html

Comment: Tried with Internet Explorer and it worked. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Google Chrome, Chrome has removed support for a JavaScript function called ‘ShowModalDialog’ that allows sites to open a window that forces users to interact with that window.

This hopefully will be addressed in a future CRM roll up, but in the mean time if you want to work in Chrome as normal, you will have to update your registry for Chrome to function correctly with CRM.

[There is a really useful post on how to do it here](http://www.crmug.com/blogs/michael-ochs/2014/09/12/crm-modal-dialogs-and-google-chrome)

Comment: Yes, that's right. I tried now with IE and it worked. Thanks, i will give your solution a try.